# ParseJson em Swift - função de login

Tags: json, rest, swift, xcode

Eu tenho um método que faz a verificação de login e senha utilizando `REST`, porem depois de ler eu preciso retornar um valor `Bool` para validar se o login foi feito.

Não sei se estou fazendo da melhor maneira, de toda forma o problema é o seguinte: ele termina de executar a função antes de me responder se o login deu certo ou errado, e só depois ele carrega essa informação.

Vejam:

```
func logarNoSistema(email: String, senha: String) -> Bool
{
    var retorno: Bool = false

    let urlPath = "http://meuendereco/api/user/login?code=xxxxxx&email=\(email)&senha=\(senha)"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)!
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()


    let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?

        var jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as! NSDictionary
        if (err != nil) {
            println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
        }

        let erro : Bool = jsonResult["erro"] as! Bool

        println(erro)
        println(jsonResult)

       //AQUI EU FAÇO A VERIFICAÇÃO SE O LOGIN DEU CERTO E SETO O RETORNO

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        })
    })
    jsonQuery.resume()


    return retorno
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é que você está fazendo uma **comunicação de dados assíncrona**, então o retorno do método `logarNoSistema` acontece logo em seguida que a chamada ao serviço é disparada, sem esperar um retorno desta.

O que você precisa fazer é com que o seu retorno venha de fato após concluir o serviço, para isso será preciso eliminar o `return` do método e utilizar o que no **Swift** chamamos de **[Closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html)**, que nada mais é do que um *callback* para o seu método.

Seu método fica assim agora (esquema só para exemplificar):

```
func logarNoSistema(email: String, senha: String, loginResponse: (response: Bool) -> ()) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://pt.stackoverflow.com")

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
        // Tratamento do JSON para então responder a condição abaixo
        if condicao {
            loginResponse(response: true)
        } else {
            loginResponse(response: false)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Onde `condicao` neste exemplo acima é o que você irá definir se houve ou não sucesso na autenticação.

Note que eu adicionei mais um argumento ao seu método, este é o método de *callback*, que receberá a resposta assim que houver. E então, faça a chamada deste método:

```
logarNoSistema("fulano@exemplo.com", senha: "xpto") { (response) -> () in
    if response {
        // Sucesso :)
    } else {
        // Falha :(
    }
}
```